# Best practise: Creating methods, different overloads

Tags: c#, methods

Let's say, for example, we have a method, which for sake of argument we'll call MethodOne;

```
public void MethodOne()
    {
      //do stuff. 
    }
```

Now let's say we want to create an optional peramater, and we might decide to create another method with the same name, that takes different overloads, for example;

```
public void MethodOne()
    {
       //do stuff.
    }

public void MethodOne(bool checkVar)
    {
       if(checkVar)
        {
           //do stuff
        }
       else
        {
          //do other stuff
        }
    }
```

So now we've got a method which has two different overload combinations(?). Is this, in practise, better than having one method, and just checking whether the optional overload is null or contains information, for example;

```
 public void MethodOne(int? testVar)
     {
        if(testVar != null)
         { 
           //do stuff
         }
     }
```

This may seem trivial with just one overload, but imagine that i've got 5 variables i want to pass through, would i create 5 methods, same name with different overloads, or just one method and check the passed variables?

Comment: Actually, if you had five parameters, and they were all optional, you could end up with up to 2^5=32 overloads.

Comment: That's besides the point : P But yeah, i get you.

Comment: If you have a method with five parameters and any or all of them can be null you have a different problem: Your method is probably doing way too much and should be split into smaller methods, each with one responsibility.

Comment: @Shane.C That's exactly the point. If you need to use 32 constructor overloads, you're doing something wrong :)

Comment: As Daniel pointed out, you probably need to check the cohesion of your method. What you are describing sounds like communicational cohesion: the code that you are putting together is together for the purpose of operating on the same data. It is generally advisable to strive for higher cohesion like functional cohesion, where all the code in your method participates to a single well-defined task. By striving for functional cohesion, your coupling should naturally go down (your parameters won't be as much of an issue)

Comment: I'd like to point out that this was purely hypothetical. I don't have any ACTUAL methods in mind, if you're worried : P I'm certainly not creating 30 methods with different overloads..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few workarounds for this. You could, for example, use an enumerator and an Object array as second parameter which contains real parameter values so that you know what to do with data by switching the enumerator... or you could just declare 5 Object parameters and then check for their type in a switch, box them accordingly and proceed. But both options are very bad practices.

I suggest you to stick on different overloads:

```
public void MethodOne(Boolean value)
{
    // Process the value...
}

public void MethodOne(Int32 value)
{
    // Process the value...
}

public void MethodOne(Int32 value, String text)
{
    // Process the value and the text...
}

// And so on...
```

Or default data in parameter declarations:

```
public void MethodOne(Int32 integer = 1, String text = "hello", ...)
{
    // Process everything inside the method...
}
```

Or parametrized methods (if every object type has a common processing):

```
public void MethodOne(params Object[] parameters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; ++i)
        // Check type of parameter and process the value...
}
```

Or methods bubbling if your design allows it (which is my favorite one as the first one is just producing a lot of code redundancies and the second one may be sometimes confusing for you or other developers working with you):

```
public void MethodOne(Int32 value)
{
    MethodOne(value, "hello");
}

public void MethodOne(Int32 value, String text)
{
    // Process everything inside the method...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
 public void MethodOne(int testVar = 0)
 {
     if(testVar != 0)
     { 
       //do stuff
     }
 }
```

Comment: There we go, made it an "int?", missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

You generally bubble down on overloads like this:

```
public void MethodOne()
{
    MethodOne(1)
}
public void MethodOne(int testVar)
{
    MethodOne(testVar, "test")
}
public void MethodOne(int testVar, string testString)
{
    MethodOne(testVar, testString, null)
}
public void MethodOne(int testVar, string testString, object testObject)
{
    // Do your actual code here
}
```

This would be equivalent to

```
public void MethodOne(int testVar = 1, string testString = "test", object testObject = null)
{
    // Do your actual code here
}
```

But usually you should prever overloads over default parameters. Also, by 'bubbling down' like in my example you avoid having redundant code or redundant 'default parameters'

Answer (score 2):

As the number of arguments increase, I wouldn't want to look through a method's nested if/else logic to determine what arguments are being used or not. It's hard to read, understand,  maintain and can lead to bugs.  Use overloads and keep your methods concise, lean and maintainable.

Comment: +1, spot on. I'll bet this would be most people's thoughts, especially if you took over someone elses code.